# What is the smallest multiple of 77 that is greater than 70,000? 700,000?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics

> What is the smallest multiple of $77$ that is greater than $70000$? $700000$?

How would you approach this question? My first thought was to factorize the $77$ into $7$ and $11$ but then how would you choose the exponents?

Comment: Just calculate?

Comment: A useful fact for this: $1001 = 77 \cdot 13$.

Comment: As the answers suggest - the easiest way of doing this is to notice that divisibility by $11$ pretty much gets you there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you can do this by first dividing by $77$, obtaining some remainder $r$. If we then add $77-r$ to the number, we obtain the smallest such multiple.

Comment: this is good, but dividing 70000/77 is hard!

Comment: @Permian It's definitely doable though.

Comment: Try it, @Permian it's easier than you think.

Comment: @MattSamuel just about

Answer (score 2):

We know $70000 \equiv 0 {\pmod 7}$. Next we compute its residue under mod 11.

$$
70000=7\cdot 10^4 \equiv 7 \cdot (-1)^4\pmod{11}
$$

I will leave the rest for you.

Answer (score 1):

A multiple of $77$ is multiple of $7$ and $11$ simultaneously.

$70070$ is clearly multiple of $11$. (The two $7$'s are placed in odd and even places; the alternating sum is zero. )

It is obviously multiple of $7$. Hence answer is $\boxed{70070}$.

By exactly same logic, the other number is $\boxed{700007}$.